# From the sample data given below, remove duplicates on the combination of Name and Age and print results

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hadoop, hive, duplicates

remove duplicates on the combination of Name and Age and print results using spark-sql

```
Name    Age Location
Rajesh  21  London
Suresh  28  California
Sam 26  Delhi
Rajesh  21  Gurgaon
Manish  29  Bengaluru
```

```
CREATE TABLE DETAILS
(
    NAME STRING,
    AGE INT,
    LOCATION STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
FIELDS TERMINATE BY '\t'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

```
======================================================================
LOAD DATA INPATH  '/FOLDER/TO/question.txt  INTO DETAILS;
======================================================================
CREATE TABLE DETAILS_FILTERED AS
SELECT NAME,AGE,LOCATION FROM DETAILS GROUP BY NAME,AGE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number or min/max aggregation. It wold be better if you have some column like timestamp to pick latest/first record pewr user+age. In that case you could include it in the row_number's order_by clause.

Examples for Hive:

```
select Name,Age,Location
from 
(
select Name,Age,Location, 
       row_number() over(partition by NAME,AGE order by Location) rn --order by makes function more deterministic
from details
)
where rn=1 --filter duplicates
```

OR

```
select Name,Age,max(Location) Location  
  from details
 group by Name,Age --aggregate
```